# But wait! We skipped a day!

Tags: wordplay, situation, time

Today is October 4th and tomorrow will be October 6th. Explain!

---

Note: I just thought of this one day and decided to post it here. Please don't leave too many downvotes. :(

Comment: What a half-coincidence, if the second date was October 15th, the explanation [it's 1582](https://theuijunkie.com/october-5th-october-14th-1582/) would fit perfectly :)

Comment: Is this one of those "C U Next Tuesday" things? :-)

Comment: The new tag might be a nudge in the right direction!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking advantage of a slight grammatical/temporal ambiguity:

> Today is October 4th. At the moment tomorrow is October 5th, but if I wait a few more hours, tomorrow will be October 6th.
>  So yes, today is October 4th, and tomorrow will be October 6th.

Comment: Nice job! :):) This is correct.

Comment: I don't think that's how grammar works...

Comment: [Macbeth](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/56964/speech-tomorrow-and-tomorrow-and-tomorrow) wouldn't agree…

Comment: @Stef While it is unusual for this to apply to the word "tomorrow", this is exactly how grammar works in some other cases where a word acts as a reference to something variable, for example "The president will be making a speech" and "The president will be someone else after the election".

Comment: @Stef The ambiguity lies on the words "will be"; it's not strictly temporal, in the sense it implies the future but not *when* in the future.

Answer (score 14):

The intended answer could be that

> you started speaking the sentence just before midnight, so halfway through the sentence, the day changed over.

Comment: I was thinking about this but thought he would present the situation as a quote if that was the case. Well lets see, +1 anyway

Comment: Cool answer, but @LukasRotter is correct. The puzzle is not written as a quote.

Answer (score 4):

Is this because you:

> will cross the international dateline from west to east at midnight on the 4th?

Comment: Should be the other way around.

Comment: I was thinking like a pacman

Comment: This solution allowed my wife to skip one of her birthdays, so she never turned 30.

Comment: Very interesting but it is more simple than that!

Comment: @FlanMan Doctors hate that trick.